# Laravel 5.7 Passport oauth - Single client for multiple users

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

Is there a way I could use the same OAuth client for all my users instead of using one client per user?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did it work or not work? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried using the Password Grant Client for my API. I think that method will work but I still need to bypass the username and password validation as both are being validating via a Front Interface

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Password Grant Client you can pass a username and password to the client and it will authenticate your users with only one client.

To protect your routes use the `auth` middleware and the `api` guard.

Remember to set the driver for your `api` guard to `passport`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#password-grant-tokens

Use this link to help you.

Comment: I need that exact same thing, but avoiding the username and password request, as I validate those two via front.

Comment: Are you attempting to build a token based api?

Comment: How are you validating the username & password already? If you use the Password Grant client then that will provide you with an access token you can use to make requests.

Comment: Via a front-end login.  I need to use the same client "ID" and client "Secret" for all of my current users. At the moment, my project works fine if I use one client per user, but what I strictly need is to use the SAME passport client for all of my users. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes that is fundamentally how the password grant client works - which is why you can't use the `CheckClientCredentials` middleware. When you complete the front end login using this client you will be given a response containing an `access_token` that you can pass in your Authorization header to get access to your guarded routes

Comment: I'm not using CheckClientCredentials middleware. My OAuth proyect should work similar to when you log in to Spotify using your Facebook/Twitter account. Another thing to take into account is that once I log in via front-end, I MUST use 'authorization_code' as 'grant_type' value

Comment: You won't be able to perform authentication with the same client if you aren't using the password_grant grant_type. Are you using a 3rd party to provide your authentication?

Comment: No, I'm the OAuth in this scenario. In my previous example, my project would take the role of facebook, and I would need to authorize any registered user by ONE SINGLE secret key. Maybe Passport isn't the way to go

Comment: That's the opposite of what i'm looking for actually. Socialite emulates the consumer, not the OAuth, and my proyect is, in fact, on OAuth. What I need is simple: Modify the way Passport works so that I don't have to create one client per user, but manage all users authentications with one single passport client. I'll keep looking, thanks for the support!

Comment: I ran `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` then `php artisan passport:client` and it worked. I think there must be an issue if you create a client via frontend instead of using the terminal

Answer (score 0):

There must be an issue when creating a client via front end.

I ran

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
```

Then created a user manually.

next

```
php artisan passport:client
```